# Sitecore Configuration Factory - Call method with more than one argument

Tags: configuration, dependency-injection, sitecore, factory

I have read John West's article on the Site Configuration Factory (http://www.sitecore.net/unitedkingdom/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/02/The-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS-Configuration-Factory.aspx)

I'm trying implement it in a custom link provider.

I want the Configuration Factory to call the following method in the link provider:

```csharp
public void AddSitePath(String site, String path)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Here's the config (although I've tried several similar variations).

```xml
<add name="sitecore" type="MyProject.Providers.CustomLinkProvider, MyProject" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="filePath" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false">
    <sitePaths hint="list:AddSitePath">
        <sitePath>
            <site>SiteOneName</site>
            <path>/product-range/</path>           
        </sitePath>
        <sitePath >
            <site>SiteTwoName</site>
            <path>/items-for-sale/</path>
        </sitePath>            
    </sitePaths>
</add >
```

I'm getting the following error message:
Could not find add method: AddSitePath (type: MyProject.Providers.CustomLinkProvider)

I suspected that the problem was that I was trying to pass  2 parameters into the method, and sure enough, when I tested it with a single parameter version it worked.

What do I need to change in either the config or the class code to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you can't supply 2 arguments. Instead, you pass in a single XmlNode object, which contains everything you you need. You have to extract the information from the XmlNode within the method.

Something along the lines of:

```csharp
public void AddSitePath(XmlNode arg)
{
   // pick apart the XmlNode and do stuff
}
```

```xml
<sitePaths hint="raw:AddSitePath">
    <sitePath site="SiteNameOne" path="/product-range/">
    <sitePath site="SiteNameTwo" path="/items-for-sale/">            
</sitePaths>
```

Note that you have to use the 'raw' prefix instead of 'list'